# SQL Select only records with no duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I would like to ask how to select in a column those records with no duplicates, meaning it only occurs once in the whole column. I tried the query below wherein I'll add a column in the results which counts the number of occurences of this record and then try to filter the unique via where but I can't seem to make it work.

```
Select tab1.[Column 0], Count(*) As NumOfMessage
from tab1 where NumOfMessage = 1 group by tab.[Column 0]
```

I appreciate your help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate?  Can you provide sample data?

Comment: Yes provide some data with your table schema

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `HAVING` clause :

```
SELECT [tab1].[Column 0]
     , COUNT(*) AS [NumOfMessage]
FROM [tab1]  
GROUP BY [tab].[Column 0] 
HAVING COUNT([tab].*) = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing that by "duplicate" you mean that the value in `[Column 0]` only appears once.

You can do this with window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by [Column 0]) as cnt
      from tab1 t
     ) t
where cnt = 1;
```